# How to custom LinearLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Like this effect (show half of the item) how to achieve it，I try to use custom `LinearLayoutManager`, but failed because I cannot understand `onMeasure` method.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question, but you can try LinearLayout with `weightSum` and assign the `layout_weight` to child items. If you have exactly 2 child items you can provide `weightSum` as 2 and `layout_weight` as 1 in respective child item. Also make sure you make `layout_width` as **0dp** for child items.

Comment: `weightSum` is perfectly **optional**.

Comment: Maybe you're wrong ? This is a RecyclerView , LinearLayout is not LinearLayoutManager ,or  I can't understand?

Comment: Misunderstood the question completely. Well if you want to have the effect like you shown in image, I would suggest to use ViewPager instead of Recycler View and you can specify the page width to achieve the desired result. You can refer this link https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, if it is single, then it will be solved, However.It is multi row (not fixed) , so i want to use recyclerview to achieve it

Comment: Use RecyclerView for Vertical scrolling. But use viewPager for horizontal scrolling item. The problem with RecyclerView set as horizontal is that scrolling will not scroll single item. You will have to customise a lot to achieve single item scrolling like Google Play app.